# Yii2 Kartik mdfp not showing watermark

Tags: yii2, mpdf, kartik-v

I use kartik\mpdf\Pdf; However when i add a watermark it does not show on the pdf generated.
here is my code

```
    $pdf = new Pdf([
        'mode' => Pdf::MODE_UTF8, // leaner size using standard fonts
        'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
        'filename' => $model->code . '.pdf',
        'content' => $this->render('_pdf', [
            'models' => [$model],
            'title' => $title,
        ]),
        'options' => [
            'title' => $title,
        ],
        'methods' => [
            'SetHeader' => [$header . $date],
            'SetTitle' => '#' . $model->code,
            'SetWatermarkImage' => [\yii\helpers\Url::to(['/images/logo.png'])],
        ],
    ]);
    return $pdf->render();
```

Answer (score 0):

well I checked the mpdf original documentation they have

```
$pdf->SetWatermarkImage('image file')
```

I tried using the same but it didn't work.

But this worked for me

```
'options' => [
            'title' => $title,
            'showWatermarkImage' => true,
        ],
```